# Convert all the elements in a file into a array in haskell

Tags: file, haskell

I have a file which contains a set of 200,000+ words and I want the program to read the data and store it in array and form a new array with all the 200,000+ words.

I wrote the code as

```
import System.IO
main = do 
    handle <- openFile "words.txt" ReadMode
    contents <- hGetContents handle
    con <- lines contents
    putStrLn ( show  con)
    hClose handle
```

But it is giving error as type error at line 5

And the text file is a of the form

```
ABRIDGMENT
ABRIDGMENTS
ABRIM
ABRIN
ABRINS
ABRIS
```

and so on

what are the amendments in the code that it can can form a array of words

I solved it in python (HTH)

```
def  readFile():
    allWords = []
    for word  in open ("words.txt"):
        allWords.append(word.strip())
    return allWords
```

Comment: As a thumb rule, use `x <- action` when you want to perform IO, and `let x = expression` when you want to evaluate a pure (side effects-free) expression. In your code `lines contents` is pure: you can tell it because the type of `lines` does not involve `IO`, unlike e.g. `openFile`.

Comment: Do note that the common pattern here would not necessarily be to use an array, but this depends entirely on what you would afterwards use the data for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe

```
readFile "words.txt" >>= return . words
```

with type

```
:: IO [String]
```

or you can write

```
getWordsFromFile :: String -> IO [String]
getWordsFromFile file = readFile file >>= return . words
```

and use as

```
main = do
  wordList <- getWordsFromFile "words.txt"
  putStrLn $ "File contains " ++ show (length wordList) ++ " words."
```

Very constructive comments from @sanityinc and @Sarah (thanks!):

@sanityinc: *"Other options: `fmap words $ readFile file` or `words <$> readFile file` if you've imported `<$>` from `Control.Applicative`"*

@Sarah: *"To elaborate a bit, whenever you see `foo >>= return . bar` you can (and should) replace it with `fmap bar foo` because you're not actually using the extra powers that come with `Monad` and in most cases restricting yourself to a needlessly complex type is not beneficial. This will be even more true in the future where `Applicative` is a superclass of `Monad`"*

Comment: `concatMap words . lines` should be equivalent to just `words`

Comment: Other options: `fmap words $ readFile file` or `words <$> readFile file` if you've imported `<$>` from `Control.Applicative`.

Comment: To elaborate a bit, whenever you see `foo >>= return . bar` you can (and should) replace it with `fmap bar foo` because you're not actually using the extra powers that come with `Monad` and in most cases restricting yourself to a needlessly complex type is not beneficial. This will be even more true in the future where `Applicative` is a superclass of `Monad`.